# Trying to remove the third column of a table when the browser gets smaller (CSS)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've made a table with 4 col and 4 rows. As the browser gets smaller, I want to have the table get smaller as well, by removing first the 4th col, then as it gets even smaller, the 3rd col.

I was able to remove the 4th col, using a media query and:

```
table th:last-child,
table td:last-child {
    display:none;
}
```

I've tried to get it to work for the third column using

```
table th:nth-last-child (2),
table td:nth-last-child (2){
    display:none;
}
```

but it will not work.

Thanks for the help!

Find the full code:https://jsfiddle.net/Kahealani1996/vtjf5dnr/

Comment: Bear in mind the information you're trying to convey; in this situation you're removing information which is, I imagine, somewhat essential; the user is almost certain to need to know the *where* as well as the *when*. Perhaps `overflow-x: scroll` (or `auto`) might be more useful? Or shorter headings?

Comment: Yeah I had thought of that, but it would show up if they expanded, so that if they are looking on a smaller screen, it would just be the when. Thanks for your help though

Answer (score 2):

The only problem is that between nth-last-child and the (2) there should be **no whitespace**. Otherwise it works perfectly fine. So your code should be:

```
    table th:nth-last-child(2),
    table td:nth-last-child(2){
        display:none;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this code.

```
<style>
table {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    width:460px;
    margin:15px;
    display:block;
    border:double 7px;
    padding:10px;
    line-height:40px;
}
table tr {
    text-align:center;
}
table th {
    font-size:20px;
    width:100px;
}
table td {
    font-size:17px;
}
@media (max-width:768px) {/*Extra-Small Screens*/
table tr th:last-child,  table tr td:last-child {
    display:none;
}
table {
    width:360px;
}
}
@media (max-width:617px) {/*Extra*/
table {
    width:300px;
}
}
@media (max-width:536px) {/*Extra*/
table tr th:nth-last-child(2),  table tr td:nth-last-child(2) {
    display:none;
}
table {
    width:170px;
}
}
</style>
```